# In R, how can I visualize how the frequency counts within two columns compares to another baseline column across time?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose you had the following dataframe:

```
#Loads library.
library(ggplot2)

#Creates vectors.
Day<-c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
ACounts<-c(3, 4, 3, 2, 6, 5, 7, 8, 6, 6)
BCounts<-c(1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3)
CCounts<-c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1)
ACumulative<-cumsum(ACounts)
BCumulative<-cumsum(BCounts)
CCumulative<-cumsum(CCounts)
ACCumulativePerc<-ACumulative/CCumulative
BCCumulativePerc<-BCumulative/CCumulative
CCCumulativePerc<-CCumulative/CCumulative

#Creates dataframe.
df<-data.frame(Day=Day, 
               ACounts=ACounts, 
               BCounts=BCounts, 
               CCounts=CCounts,
               ACumulative=ACumulative, 
               BCumulative=BCumulative,
               CCumulative=CCumulative,
               ACCumulativePerc=ACCumulativePerc,
               BCCumulativePerc=BCCumulativePerc,
               CCCumulativePerc=CCCumulativePerc)

   Day ACounts BCounts CCounts ACumulative BCumulative CCumulative ACCumulativePerc BCCumulativePerc CCCumulativePerc
1    1       3       1       1           3           1           1         3.000000         1.000000                1
2    2       4       3       2           7           4           3         2.333333         1.333333                1
3    3       3       2       3          10           6           6         1.666667         1.000000                1
4    4       2       4       1          12          10           7         1.714286         1.428571                1
5    5       6       3       1          18          13           8         2.250000         1.625000                1
6    6       5       2       2          23          15          10         2.300000         1.500000                1
7    7       7       1       2          30          16          12         2.500000         1.333333                1
8    8       8       4       3          38          20          15         2.533333         1.333333                1
9    9       6       5       3          44          25          18         2.444444         1.388889                1
10  10       6       3       1          50          28          19         2.631579         1.473684                1
```

Suppose groups "A" and "B" were given a treatment resulting in higher counts each day.  You can see this if you plot the cumulative counts which displays the following:

```
#Creates cumulative figure.
ggplot(df, aes(Day)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = ACumulative, colour = "ACumulative"), size=1.25) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = BCumulative, colour = "BCumulative"), size=1.25) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = CCumulative, colour = "CCumulative"), size=1.25) + 
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 14)) +
    annotate("text", x=11.5, y=50, label= "50 \n (2.63X)") + 
    annotate("text", x=11.5, y=28, label= "28 \n (1.47X)") + 
    annotate("text", x=11.5, y=19, label= "19 \n (1X)")
```

[image]

What might best the best way to visualize how the counts of "A" and "B" across time compare to that of "C" with "C" serving as a baseline? In other words, how can I visualize the effects the treatment had on "A" and "B" with "C", which received no treatment, serving as a baseline?

Comment: Could you divide/subtract C from A and B and then just plot A and B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract `ACounts` and `BCounts` with `CCounts` and take cumulative sum of them to plot. Instead of using multiple `geom_line` you can get the data in long format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  transmute(Day,
            A = cumsum(ACounts - CCounts), 
            B = cumsum(BCounts - CCounts)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Day, names_to = 'group') %>%
  ggplot() + aes(Day, value, color = group) + 
  geom_line(size = 2) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 10)) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]